# NullInjectorError: No provider for HubService

Tags: angular, signalr, angular-services

I started learning about signalr and angular and I want to create an app that can speak with the browser using signalr.
I am using ngx-signalR-hubservice in angular to communicate with the signalr application. I created a simple service to test the code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HubService,
  Hub,
  HubSubscription,
  HubWrapper
} from 'ngx-signalR-hubservice';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
@Hub({hubName: 'DALHub'})
export class UserConnectionServiceService {
  private hubWrapper: HubWrapper;
  constructor(private hub: HubService) {
    this.hubWrapper = this.hub.register(this);
    this.hub.connect({url: 'http://localhost:10476/signalr'});
}
  async SaveKey() {
    await this.hubWrapper.invoke('SaveKey', 'yedidya', 'kfiry');
    console.log('awesome');
  }
  @HubSubscription()
  OK() {
    console.log('GOT IT');
  }
}
```

this is my app component

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HubService } from 'ngx-signalr-hubservice';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SignUpComponent,
    LogInComponent
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  providers: [HubService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and here is the code where I use the service I created

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UserConnectionServiceService} from '../../Services/UserConnectionService/user-connection-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-up',
  templateUrl: './sign-up.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-up.component.css']
})
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
  public save(): void {
    this.hub.SaveKey();
  }
  constructor(private hub: UserConnectionServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

but when I try to run it (I use ng serve) I get the following error in the browser

> ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SignUpComponent ->
>   HubService]:  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[SignUpComponent ->
>   HubService]:  NullInjectorError: No provider for HubService! at
>   NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get
>   (core.js:979)

Comment: Try adding it to the module `imports` as well.

Comment: have you added `UserConnectionServiceService ` to providers as well and add import statement  HubService into `UserConnectionServiceService`?

Comment: Share your `angular.cli.json` or `angular.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the AppModule

```
 import { HubService } from 'ngx-signalr-hubservice';
```

In UserConnectionServiceService:

```
import {
  HubService,
  Hub,
  HubSubscription,
  HubWrapper
} from 'ngx-signalR-hubservice';
```

Is it supposed to be `ngx-signalr-hubservice`?

I believe it is a typo from the author. Here's the npm link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-signalr-hubservice

Comment: @Yedidyakfir No problem. I believe it's a typo from the author, check the link i posted.